# Fade in Words from a Word Cloud Randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have build the a word cloud (you can check it out at http://www.cybernetiksolutions.com/wordcloud )

Currently the cloud fades every word in all at one time. I would like to have the words fade in randomly from top to bottom. The idea was inspired by www.vudu.com and http://wonderwall.msn.com . I figure in the right direction on how I can make this happen would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest an algorithm that picks a random word from the remaining hidden words so each cycle is guaranteed to show a new word until all are shown. This starts with a list of all the words, then picks one at random, removes it from the list, animates it, then repeats the cycle picking the next one from the ones remaining in the list, etc...  Rather than a timer, it uses the completion function from the animation to kick off the next word.

```
function fadeInRandom() {
    var words = $('#wordcloud a');
    function fadeNext() {
        if (words.length) {
            var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
            var item = words.eq(index);
            words = words.not(item);
            item.animate({color: "#89171a"}, 800, fadeNext);
        }
    }
    fadeNext();
}
fadeInRandom();
```

If you had so many words that you wanted to be fading multiple words in at the same time, you can simply be doing this (which will do four at a time):

```
function fadeInRandom() {
    var words = $('#wordcloud a');
    function fadeNext() {
        if (words.length) {
            var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
            var item = words.eq(index);
            words = words.not(item);
            item.animate({color: "#89171a"}, 800, fadeNext);
        }
    }
    fadeNext();
    fadeNext();
    fadeNext();
    fadeNext();
}
fadeInRandom();
```

Or if you want four at a time and evenly spaced, you could do this:

```
function fadeInRandom() {
    var words = $('#wordcloud a');
    function fadeNext() {
        if (words.length) {
            var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
            var item = words.eq(index);
            words = words.not(item);
            item.animate({color: "#89171a"}, 800, fadeNext);
        }
    }
    fadeNext();
    setTimeout(fadeNext, 50);
    setTimeout(fadeNext, 100);
    setTimeout(fadeNext, 150);
    setTimeout(fadeNext, 200);
    setTimeout(fadeNext, 250);
    setTimeout(fadeNext, 300);
    setTimeout(fadeNext, 350);
    setTimeout(fadeNext, 400);
    setTimeout(fadeNext, 450);
    setTimeout(fadeNext, 500);
    setTimeout(fadeNext, 550);
    setTimeout(fadeNext, 600);
    setTimeout(fadeNext, 650);
    setTimeout(fadeNext, 700);
    setTimeout(fadeNext, 750);
}
fadeInRandom();
```

Change your whole document.ready() code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var count = 0;

    for(count=0;count<words.length;count++){
        $('#wordcloud').append('<a href="'+words[count].url+'">'+words[count].text+'</a>')
    }

    for(count=0;count<6;count++){
        $('#wordcloud').append($('#wordcloud').html());
    }

    for(count = 0 ; count < $('#wordcloud a').length ; count++){
        $('#wordcloud a').eq(count).css('font-size', $.randomBetween(10, 20)+'px');
    }

    // Random Fade In

    function fadeInRandom() {
        var words = $('#wordcloud a');

        function fadeNext() {
            if (words.length) {
                var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
                var item = words.eq(index);
                words = words.not(item);
                item.animate({color: "#89171a"}, 800, fadeNext);
            }
        }
        fadeNext();
    setTimeout(fadeNext, 50);
    setTimeout(fadeNext, 100);
    setTimeout(fadeNext, 150);
    setTimeout(fadeNext, 200);
    setTimeout(fadeNext, 250);
    setTimeout(fadeNext, 300);
    setTimeout(fadeNext, 350);
    setTimeout(fadeNext, 400);
    setTimeout(fadeNext, 450);
    setTimeout(fadeNext, 500);
    setTimeout(fadeNext, 550);
    setTimeout(fadeNext, 600);
    setTimeout(fadeNext, 650);
    setTimeout(fadeNext, 700);
    setTimeout(fadeNext, 750);
    }
    fadeInRandom();

    // Fade In and Fade Out on Hover

    $("#wordcloud a").hover(function() {  
        $(this).stop().animate({ color: "#89171a"}, 800);  
    },function() {  
        $(this).stop().animate({ color: "#2f2f2f" }, 800);  
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I have been trying to get option three to work and I have been un successful. Im sure its something thing trivial but I cant figure it out. I uploaded everything to the same site http://www.cybernetiksolutions.com/wordcloud

Comment: @thebradnet - you never called `fadeInRandom()` to initiate it.  Put a call to `fadeInRandom()` right after the function definition.

Comment: I believe I just did that and still nothing. I originally had the following line of code in my script to allow everything to fade in all at once '$('#wordcloud').delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);' If I remove and nothing will load even if your code isnt present. I have gone through to make sure everything is closes and everything is from what I can tell. I have uploaded a revised copy to the link provided before. Thank you for your time and patience. I am fairly new to JQuery and Javascript and I am trying to learn by trial and error. So again thank you.

Comment: You inserted something wrong and now have a javascript syntax error so the code doesn't run.  I've added a copy of your whole document.ready() block to the end of my answer.  Try it like that (make sure you replace your entire block with everything I have).

Comment: I replaced everything and its still not loading. I have uploaded my results to the link above. Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Remove this line: `$('#wordcloud').css('display', 'none');`  It's working when that line is removed, but you're probably going to need to add more lines of `setTimeout(fadeNext, xxx);` with different values of xxx because there are so many words.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
var i = 2;
setInterval(function(){
$('#wordcloud a').eq(Math.floor(Math.random()*i)).animate({ color: "#89171a"}, 800);
i*= 4
}, 800)
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple method would be to loop through each word and assign a randomly selected fade in speed to each individual word. For example...

```
$('.words').each(function(index, value) { // Using the class assigned to each word
    rn = $.randomBetween(200, 5000); // Or whatever random call you're using
    $(this).fadeIn(rn);
});
```